# java gui help needed

Tags: java, user-interface

I need some help with gui in java. I am an absolute beginner with java and programming. I copy pasted this code in BlueJ

```
import javax.swing.*;
class gui{
    public static void main(){
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First GUI");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(300,300);
       JButton button = new JButton("Press");
       frame.getContentPane().add(button); // Adds Button to content pane of frame
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and I didn't get the desired results and this is what showed up in the terminal window:

> Device "Mobile Intel(R) 45 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)" (\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed :
> WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like it says, download the latest graphics driver on the official Intel website and install,then try it again.